# Expectation of the trace of inverse of a Gaussian random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Given a $N×M$ random complex gaussian  matrix $X$ and $N×K$ random complex gaussian  matrix $Y$ I'm interested in approximating the expectation expressed as:
  \begin{align}
E[trace({(aX{X^H} + I)^{ - 1}}Y{Y^H})]
\end{align}
a Is a positive given variable. I know that $XX^H$ and $YY^H$ have Wishard distribution, However. I can not approximate the problem value. Thanks!

For context, this problem relates to the quality of MIMO communication link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the matrices $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Since the trace commutes with the expectation value, and since the expectation value of the product of independent random variables is the product of expectation values, we have
$$
F(a)=\mathbb{E}\bigl[{\rm tr}\,\bigl({(aX{X^H} + I)^{ - 1}}Y{Y^H}\bigr)\bigr]={\rm tr}\bigl(\,\mathbb{E}[(aX{X^H} + I)^{ - 1}]\mathbb{E}[Y{Y^H}]\bigr).$$
The second factor is simply $K$ times the unit matrix, so
$$F(a)=K\,{\rm tr}\,\mathbb{E}[(aX{X^H} + I)^{ - 1}].$$
We can now again exchange trace and expectation value, to rewrite this as an integral over the eigenvalues $\mu_k$ of $XX^H$, with density $\rho(\mu)$,
$$F(a)=K\int \rho(\mu)(a\mu+1)^{-1}\,d\mu.$$
The density $\rho(\mu)$ is known, for large matrix size it is the Marcenko-Pastur distribution.

<sub>For the Marcenko-Pastur distribution, so for $M\geq N\gg 1$, I find
$$F(a)=\frac{K}{2a} \left(\sqrt{a^2 (M-N)^2+2 a (M+N)+1}+a (N-M)-1\right).$$</sub>

Comment: please can I employing the same approach can  I used  Wishart distribution??

Comment: I am using the Wishart distribution: firstly when I use that $\mathbb{E}[YY^H]=K$ times the identity, and secondly the Marcenko-Pastur distribution is derived from the Wishart distribution.

Comment: Is the answering missing a factor of min(M, N) since the trace is the summation of all eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0):

The following argument is quite similar to Carlo Beenakker's.

---

For simplicity, I only consider the real case. I'm also going to use different symbols for the sizes of the matrices. Let $X$ be an $n \times d$ random matrix with iid rows from $N(0,\Sigma)$ let $Y$ be a $m \times d$ random matrix independent of $X$, with iid rows from $N(0,S)$. Set $\widehat \Sigma := X^\top X/n$ and $\widehat S := Y^\top Y/m$. Let $F(a)$ be the expression you wish to evaluate and set $\lambda=1/(na)$. Note that
$$
F(a) = \frac{m}{na} \mathbb E\,[\operatorname{tr} \widehat S(\widehat\Sigma + \lambda I_d)^{-1} ]
$$

Then, in the limit $n,d \to \infty$ such that $d/n \to \phi \in (0,\infty)$, we have
$$
\mathbb E\,[\operatorname{tr} \widehat S  (\widehat\Sigma + \lambda I_d)^{-1} \mid Y] \simeq \operatorname{tr}  \widehat S(\Sigma + \kappa I_d)^{-1},
$$
where $\kappa = \kappa(\lambda,n)$ is the unique nonnegative solution to the equation $\kappa - \lambda = \kappa \operatorname{df}_1(\kappa)/n$, where
$$
\operatorname{df}_1(\kappa) := \operatorname{tr}\Sigma (\Sigma + \kappa I_d)^{-1}.
$$
We deduce that
$$
\mathbb E\,[\operatorname{tr} \widehat S(\widehat \Sigma + \lambda I_d)^{-1} ]  \simeq \mathbb E\,[\operatorname{tr} \widehat S (\Sigma + \kappa I_d)^{-1}] = \mathbb E\,[\operatorname{tr}S (\Sigma + \kappa I_d)^{-1}].
$$

In your question, you have $\Sigma=S=I_d$, and so
$$
\mathbb E\,[\operatorname{tr}\widehat S (\widehat \Sigma + \lambda I_d)^{-1}] \simeq \frac{d}{1+\kappa}.
$$
Moreover, $\kappa$ is now given by the following well-known formula which is reminiscent of the Marchenko-Pastur  distribution
$$
\kappa = \frac{\lambda + \overline \phi + \sqrt{(\lambda + \overline\phi)^2 + 4\lambda}}{2},
$$
where $\overline \phi := \phi-1$.

Simplify...